# What is optimal orientation of drip holes on driplines?

Tags: irrigation, drip-system

I want know what are the best orientations for driplines? especially those that are under the surface.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer: best is down or sideways because chance or getting dirt in is lower than if they would be oriented upwards.
Still, there is not a very big difference between positions.

Best to keep the line used and to add an air valve that would avoid negative pressure from sucking dirt.